# How to use pipe (|) and comma (,) together in JQ 1.4?

Tags: json, jq

I using JQ 1.4 on Windows 64 bit machine.

Below are the contents input file (`JSON.txt`)

```
    {
        "name": "Google",
        "location":
                {
                        "street": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
                        "city": "Mountain View",
                        "state": "California",
                        "country": "US"
                },
        "employees":
                [
                        {
                                "name": "Michael",
                                "division": "Engineering"
                        },
                        {
                                "name": "Laura",
                                "division": "HR"
                        },
                        {
                                "name": "Elise",
                                "division": "Marketing"
                        }
                ]
}
```

At the output I exect to see two results `"Google"` and `"Laura"`
I am able to get them with idividual filters.

```
1) jq ."name" JSON.txt
"Google"

2) jq ."employees|map(select(.division==\"HR\"))"[0].name JSON.txt
"Laura"
```

When I combine these two filters using comma `,`, I receive below error:

```
3) jq ."name",."employees|map(select(.division==\"HR\"))"[0].name JSON.txt
jq: error: Cannot iterate over string
null
"Laura"
```

Can someone please help to me to get below result:

```
"Google"
"Laura"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use brackets around the second part of the expression, and shorthand key filter syntax as in:

```
jq ".name, (.employees|map(select(.division==\"HR\"))[0].name)" JSON.txt
```

Comment: I tried running this..it throws error: 'map' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: hmm, forgot about the windows part; quoting fixed for windows now